# How do you animate an element to have it slide it in from the top off the page. The element is centered in the page with grid

Tags: css, reactjs, grid, animate.css

https://codesandbox.io/s/github/Critter4Dinner/Calculator

How to animate component that is centered both vertically and horizontally with grid, how do you animate it to slide in from the top from off the page?

In my index.css file this is what I have so far..

```
html, body, #root, #root>div {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    display: grid;
    background-color: #330055;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 100 1000'%3E%3Cg %3E%3Ccircle fill='%23330055' cx='50' cy='0' r='50'/%3E%3Cg fill='%2338005b' %3E%3Ccircle cx='0' cy='50' r='50'/%3E%3Ccircle cx='100' cy='50' r='50'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3Ccircle fill='%233e0160' cx='50' cy='100' r='50'/%3E%3Cg fill='%23430166' %3E%3Ccircle cx='0' cy='150' r='50'/%3E%3Ccircle cx='100' cy='150' r='50'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3Ccircle fill='%2349026c' cx='50' cy='200' r='50'/%3E%3Cg fill='%234e0272' %3E%3Ccircle cx='0' cy='250' r='50'/%3E%3Ccircle cx='100' cy='250' r='50'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3Ccircle fill='%23540377' cx='50' cy='300' r='50'/%3E%3Cg fill='%235a037d' %3E%3Ccircle cx='0' cy='350' r='50'/%3E%3Ccircle cx='100' cy='350' r='50'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3Ccircle fill='%23600483' cx='50' cy='400' r='50'/%3E%3Cg fill='%23660489' %3E%3Ccircle cx='0' cy='450' r='50'/%3E%3Ccircle cx='100' cy='450' r='50'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3Ccircle fill='%236c048f' cx='50' cy='500' r='50'/%3E%3Cg fill='%23720595' %3E%3Ccircle cx='0' cy='550' r='50'/%3E%3Ccircle cx='100' cy='550' r='50'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3Ccircle fill='%2379059a' cx='50' cy='600' r='50'/%3E%3Cg fill='%237f05a0' %3E%3Ccircle cx='0' cy='650' r='50'/%3E%3Ccircle cx='100' cy='650' r='50'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3Ccircle fill='%238605a6' cx='50' cy='700' r='50'/%3E%3Cg fill='%238c04ac' %3E%3Ccircle cx='0' cy='750' r='50'/%3E%3Ccircle cx='100' cy='750' r='50'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3Ccircle fill='%239304b2' cx='50' cy='800' r='50'/%3E%3Cg fill='%239a03b8' %3E%3Ccircle cx='0' cy='850' r='50'/%3E%3Ccircle cx='100' cy='850' r='50'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3Ccircle fill='%23a103bd' cx='50' cy='900' r='50'/%3E%3Cg fill='%23a801c3' %3E%3Ccircle cx='0' cy='950' r='50'/%3E%3Ccircle cx='100' cy='950' r='50'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3Ccircle fill='%23af00c9' cx='50' cy='1000' r='50'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: contain;

    animation-name: slideFromTop;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-duration: 400ms;
  }


  @keyframes slideFromTop {
    0% {
        height: 0%;
    }
    100% {
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

This gets the element to slide in but it is not coming from off the page. i have tried using a negative percentage but it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use postion:relative or translate().

example with position:relative :

```
html, body, #root, #root>div {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    display: grid;
    background-color: #330055;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 100 1000'%3E%3Cg %3E%3Ccircle fill='%23330055' cx='50' cy='0' r='50'/%3E%3Cg fill='%2338005b' %3E%3Ccircle cx='0' cy='50' r='50'/%3E%3Ccircle cx='100' cy='50' r='50'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3Ccircle fill='%233e0160' cx='50' cy='100' r='50'/%3E%3Cg fill='%23430166' %3E%3Ccircle cx='0' cy='150' r='50'/%3E%3Ccircle cx='100' cy='150' r='50'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3Ccircle fill='%2349026c' cx='50' cy='200' r='50'/%3E%3Cg fill='%234e0272' %3E%3Ccircle cx='0' cy='250' r='50'/%3E%3Ccircle cx='100' cy='250' r='50'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3Ccircle fill='%23540377' cx='50' cy='300' r='50'/%3E%3Cg fill='%235a037d' %3E%3Ccircle cx='0' cy='350' r='50'/%3E%3Ccircle cx='100' cy='350' r='50'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3Ccircle fill='%23600483' cx='50' cy='400' r='50'/%3E%3Cg fill='%23660489' %3E%3Ccircle cx='0' cy='450' r='50'/%3E%3Ccircle cx='100' cy='450' r='50'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3Ccircle fill='%236c048f' cx='50' cy='500' r='50'/%3E%3Cg fill='%23720595' %3E%3Ccircle cx='0' cy='550' r='50'/%3E%3Ccircle cx='100' cy='550' r='50'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3Ccircle fill='%2379059a' cx='50' cy='600' r='50'/%3E%3Cg fill='%237f05a0' %3E%3Ccircle cx='0' cy='650' r='50'/%3E%3Ccircle cx='100' cy='650' r='50'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3Ccircle fill='%238605a6' cx='50' cy='700' r='50'/%3E%3Cg fill='%238c04ac' %3E%3Ccircle cx='0' cy='750' r='50'/%3E%3Ccircle cx='100' cy='750' r='50'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3Ccircle fill='%239304b2' cx='50' cy='800' r='50'/%3E%3Cg fill='%239a03b8' %3E%3Ccircle cx='0' cy='850' r='50'/%3E%3Ccircle cx='100' cy='850' r='50'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3Ccircle fill='%23a103bd' cx='50' cy='900' r='50'/%3E%3Cg fill='%23a801c3' %3E%3Ccircle cx='0' cy='950' r='50'/%3E%3Ccircle cx='100' cy='950' r='50'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3Ccircle fill='%23af00c9' cx='50' cy='1000' r='50'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: contain;
    position:relative;
    animation-name: slideFromTop;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-duration: 400ms;
  }


  @keyframes slideFromTop {
    0% {
       top: -100vh;
    }
    100% {
        top: 0;
    }
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-star-c4e68